# How to use random numbers within recursion?

Tags: haskell, recursion, random

I'm trying to select a random element from a list but that'll make the function impure thus fail to compile. What should I do to make the recursive function accept an IO action?

```
build :: Jabberwocky Integer String Syllables -> String
build (Jabberwocky 0 body syl) = body
build (Jabberwocky len body syl)
    | syl == Middle     = build (Jabberwocky (len - 1) (body ++ (rand middle)    ) Consonant)
    | syl == Consonant  = build (Jabberwocky (len - 1) (body ++ (rand consonant)) Vowel)
    | syl == Vowel      = build (Jabberwocky (len - 1) (body ++ (rand vowel)     ) Consonant)
    | syl == Ending     = build (Jabberwocky (len - 1) (body ++ (rand ending)    ) Vowel)
        where 
            rand = getStdRandom (randomR (1,6))
```

Comment: You can generate random numbers in a pure way, without the `IO` at all. You just have to pass your own generator object instead of using the global one. If you insist on using `IO`, then your signature should show it (but I wouldn't do it).

Comment: Could you elaborate? Answers I looked for so far have been saying the opposite. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926267/how-to-make-random-in-haskell-in-pure-function

Comment: Not opposite, precisely what I meant. `Jabberwocky ... -> String` is a pure function. you can't use `IO` inside of it. You'd need to either change the function to an impure one (`Jabberwocky ... -> IO String`) or stop using the global random number generator.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question. I'm still very confused. How do I write the function with monad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must carry generator into pure process (chaining new random generator state)

```
randomR_nTimes_rec :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => Int -> (a, a) -> g -> ([a], g)
randomR_nTimes_rec 0 _ g = ([], g)
randomR_nTimes_rec n i g = (x:xs, g'') where ( x, g' ) = randomR i g
                                             (xs, g'') = randomR_nTimes_rec (n - 1) i g'
```

usage

```
*Main> getStdGen  >>= return . randomR_nTimes_rec 5 (0,5)
([2,5,3,1,3],1206240749 652912057)
```

if you should carry random state into a complex process may be useful `Control.Monad.Random` [with example](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html)

Comment: I don't think this answer adds anything beyond the answers in the duplicate. Consider closevoting and answering the original question next time.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz (ok, it's duplicated, confused me "saying the opposite"...).

Comment: I just want to add to this that if you thread the generator manually, be *very* careful not to use the same generator twice. It's much easier than you think.