# How to generate a random word

Tags: python, string, list

I don't know how I would take a word from a list in Python 3.3. This is my current code:

print(random.randstr("blue","red","green","yellow"))

And I get this error:

print(random.randstr("blue","red","green","yellow"))
NameError: name 'random' is not defined

Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you make your question more clear?

Comment: You will need to generate random index values in the required range and then retrieve associated list items.

Comment: I recommend looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2926280/382936 where it is recommended to implement a function randomPick which takes a random number generator and a list and returns an element of the list: `randomPick :: RNG -> [a] -> (a, RNG)`

Comment: In what programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should import your Module or external library first.
and random module dose not have random.str() function!

Try This :

```
import random
a = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'brown', 'black']
print(random.choice(a))
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks! This worked! (I was making a random sentence generator so I saved random.choice as a variable.)